# How do I restrict a novice user from installing configuration profiles on their devices?

Tags: ios, parental-controls, apple-configurator, configuration-profiles

I noticed some novice users installed some spam configuration profiles which installed some email inboxes on their iOS devices such as 'Daily Bible Verse' or 'WEATHER ALERTS' with a email address ending in `@my.minbox.email`. This [site](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1415258-ios-advertisement-installed-a-device-profile-with-imap) has more information. How do I setup their device so that they can't install any profile? I think I can do this by creating a profile of my own and installing on their device. There is the following key that might help from [Apple's support doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html). How would I create a profile with this key and install it?

> `allowUIConfigurationProfileInstallation` - Optional. Supervised only. If
>   set to false, the user is prohibited from installing configuration
>   profiles and certificates interactively. This will default to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this key is a ‘supervised only’ key, the device must be in supervision for this key to be functional, otherwise it will have no effect.

Once your device is supervised, you can create and install a profile with the key set. You can create such a profile with Apple Configurator. Choose Restrictions as the payload, then under Functionality, uncheck ‘Allow installing configuration profiles’.

[image]

Complete the mandatory General payload, then save this profile and install it on your now-supervised device for the payload to function.